# C++ Print Total of Prime Numbers

Tags: c++

It's nothing major but I just can't figure out how to do it in my code but in the code that I currently have and I am not wanting to change it but I want my code to print the **total number of prime numbers** after my list of prime numbers within given range. Code is below

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Declaring Variables
    int i, start, end;
    int chk = 0, j;
    bool is_prime = true;

    // User Input
    cout << "\nEnter starting number: ";
    cin >> start;
    cout << "\n" "Enter final number: ";
    cin >> end;
    cout << "Number divisible by 7 from " << start << " to " << end << endl;
    cout << "******************************\n";

    // Dividing by 7
    for (i = start; i < end + 1; i++)
    {
        if (i % 7 == 0)
        {
            // Divisible Output
            cout << " " << i;
        }
    }

    // Prime Numbers
    cout << "\n\nPrime Numbers";
    cout << "\n************* \n";

    // Prime Numbers Calculation
    for (start; start <= end; start++)
    {
        for (j = 2; j < start; j++)
        {
            if (start % j == 0)
            {
                chk++;
                break;
            }
        }

        // Prime Numbers Output
        if (chk == 0)
            cout << start << " ";
        chk = 0;
    }

    cout << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Before your loop that checks for prime numbers initialize a variable named `count` to 0. When you find a prime and print it add 1 to `count` At the end `count` will contain the number of items printed.

Comment: Recommended reading: [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Comment: @RetiredNinja So to do this, above my loop for the prime numbers. Will I do something like ``count = 0``` then within the loop do ``` count++``` then at the end output it?

Comment: @gekohasnonecko Why not try it and see? (but the answer is yes).

Comment: @john The reason I am asking is because I am out currently... - Plus this didn't work (had my brother chuck it in my code for me)

Comment: If you wrote this program then adding a simple variable to count the number of items you print should be very easy.

Comment: Tried doing it and it didn't work... I'll put the block of code around the prime numbers outputs that I tried | 
`int count = 0;
if (chk == 0) {
     cout << start << " ";
count++;
chk = 0;
}
cout << "Total number of prime numbers from (" << start << " and " << end << "): " << count;`

Comment: Perhaps someone will do it for you but I will not. I said before the loop and that is inside the loop. This is not a difficult task. You also moved `chk = 0;` to an incorrect place. It was in the right place before.

Comment: if you have code that doesnt work you should ask about that rather than asking others to write it again

Answer (score 0):

Here in your code with some addition, i've printed the sum of prime numbers in the range also the total number of prime numbers.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    // Declaring Variables
    int i, start, end,total=0,count=0;
    int chk = 0, j;
    bool is_prime = true;

    // User Input
    cout << "\nEnter starting number: ";
    cin >> start;
    cout << "\n" "Enter final number: ";
    cin >> end;
    cout << "Number divisible by 7 from " << start << " to " << end << endl;
    cout << "******************************\n";

    // Dividing by 7
    for (i = start; i < end + 1; i++)
    {
        if (i % 7 == 0)
        {
            // Divisible Output
            cout << " " << i;
        }
    }

    // Prime Numbers
    cout << "\n\nPrime Numbers";
    cout << "\n************* \n";

    // Prime Numbers Calculation
    for (start; start <= end; start++)
    {
        for (j = 2; j < start; j++)
        {
            if (start % j == 0)
            {
                chk++;
                break;
            }
        }

        // Prime Numbers Output
        if (chk == 0){
            cout << start << " ";
            total = total+start;
            count++;
        }
        chk = 0;
    }
    cout << endl << "Total Of Prime Numbers:" << count;
    cout << endl << "Sum Of Prime Numbers:" << total;
    cout << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score -2):

> #include  using namespace std;
>
> int main() {
>
> ```
> // Declaring Variables
> int i, start, end,total=0,count=0;
> int chk = 0, j;
> bool is_prime = true;
>
> // User Input
> cout << "\nEnter starting number: ";
> cin >> start;
> cout << "\n" "Enter final number: ";
> cin >> end;
> cout << "Number divisible by 7 from " << start << " to " << end << endl;
> cout << "******************************\n";
>
> // Dividing by 7
> for (i = start; i < end + 1; i++)
> {
>     if (i % 7 == 0)
>     {
>         // Divisible Output
>         cout << " " << i;
>     }
> }
>
> // Prime Numbers
> cout << "\n\nPrime Numbers";
> cout << "\n************* \n";
>
> // Prime Numbers Calculation
> for (start; start <= end; start++)
> {
>     for (j = 2; j < start; j++)
>     {
>         if (start % j == 0)
>         {
>             chk++;
>             break;
>         }
>     }
>
>     // Prime Numbers Output
>     if (chk == 0){
>         cout << start << " ";
>         total = total+start;
>         count++;
>     }
>     chk = 0;
> }
> cout << endl << "Total Of Prime Numbers:" << count;
> cout << endl;
> return 0;
> ```
>
> }

Comment: If this is a citation, please give credits to the source. If this is not a citation, plaese remove the citation marks. Please make sure that your code is formatted properly. At the moment, it isn't

Comment: What was wrong before? How does this fix that problem? Some elaboration would improve this answer.

Comment: this code is perfectely fine, read the questioner statement, he's looking for "total number of prime numbers " and @DANIYAL FARUKI provided that solution . 
yeah a little issue with the formatting for the young fellow here but he shouldn't be DEGRADED by marking wrong or negative.